# position of "that is"

Tags: word-order

I'd like to know where to put "that is" when giving more precise information:

> a. John bought a wolf-like dog, a Siberian husky, that is.

> b. John bought a wolf-like dog, that is, a Siberian husky.

Are both positions correct? Can "that is" ever go to the end of a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes both positions can be used. In general "that is" flags an explanation or an addition to clear ambiguity, rather than just additional information. For example "This is a transformer, that is, a robot that can turn into a car or a truck." Or, for two Australians talking "I am going to Melbourne, the one in England that is." In this last example there is also a humourous point, because the hearer would expect the speaker to be going to the Melbourne in Australia.